# Customize theming for field collection in node add form

Tags: theming, entities

I have a field type [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) in a content type (I set it to have multi value). In field collection including some fields and I want to show the fields in the field collection in **table format** in the **node add form**. Here I want it drupal_render in the table structure that i want. Do not ask me to use [field collection table](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_table) module because it does not meet it.

Looking forward for the help from everyone.

Thank you very much.